# Unintuitive behavior of open with flags DIRECTORY and O_CREAT

Tags: linux, posix, system-calls

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.8.0 and glibc version 2.23. When I execute `open` with flags `O_DIRECTORY` and `O_CREAT` and the directory does not exist, a regular file is created instead of a directory. What workarounds exist to fix that unintuitive behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I understand the manpage of `open` correctly the combination of `O_DIRECTORY` and `O_CREAT` is not intended:

`O_DIRECTORY` should fail if the file name does not specify a directory. I interpret "a directory" as "an existing directory" here.

You might use `mkdir` first. `mkdir` will return an error code if the directory already exists. You simply ignore the value returned by `mkdir`. Then you open the file with `O_DIRECTORY`:

```
mkdir(the_file_name, your_desired_mode);
f = open(the_file_name, O_DIRECTORY);
```

Comment: So there is an error in the implementation of `open`, because it isn't returning any error to signal a bad argument combination.